# delete content of a .txt with VIM between specific words

Tags: linux, vim, text-files

I want to delete the content of a .txt between two lines thant contents keywords. Is that possible with vim?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this command:

```
:g/BEGIN/,/END/d
```

If you don't need to delete the keywords:

```
:g/BEGIN/+1,/END/-1d
```

Comment: thanks, but...the last line that I want to delete is at the End of the file, but the first line I want to delete is not the first of the file...

Comment: `BEGIN`/`END` are just keywords, change them to whatever to meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Given

> the last line that I want to delete is at the End of the file, but the first line I want to delete is not the first of the file

I'd use:

```
%s/\_.*\zs\n\=.*BEGIN\_.*END.*//
```

-> `:h /\_.`, `:h /\zs` => till the `\zs`, everything (new-lines/CR as well) that can be matched is matched (included first occurrences of BEGIN that you seem to want to ignore). Then All the line (and its previous `\n`) of the line to delete is matched, till the END (and its complete line).

Comment: Can you explain me how delete only inside keywords?

Comment: Move the `\zs` 0-length pattern to indicates where you want the matching to really start (what's before becomes just context). And add the zone-end pattern (`\ze`) as well -> `%s/\_.*\n\=.*BEGIN\zs\_.*\zeEND.*//`